# Office Online cannot preview "EXCEL" documents only

Tags: sharepoint

We have SharePoint 2019 and running Office Online(v 16.0.10338.20039) as well. Recently we have encountered a strange message where it says "***We can't show a preview of this item.***" This is only happening for all excel files. All other office related files(word, ppt, pdf, etc) are working fine.

Did someone else come across this and has a workaround solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When trying to open the excel file, please check the ULS logs on your OOS server. It is located at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\OfficeWebApps\Data\Logs\ULS. That should give you more clues to troubleshoot.

Comment: I tried but honestly not sure what to exactly look for regarding excel preview. there's nothing mentioned that points to excel preview. maybe if i attach the log.

Comment: You could attach the logs.